# Raspbian Jessie - static IP does not work

Tags: raspbian-jessie

Has anyone been able to tackle this Jessie update and connect to the internet at all when setting up a static IP using the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

I have tried these variations

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=numbers/24 OR #/24
static router=gateway ip
static OR #static
domain_name_server=8.8.8.8  OR  with just gateway ip
```

This is so annoying it seems my only option might be to disable the `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: I write up notes on the Pi in book form that can be found here https://leanpub.com/pi.  On pages starting at 176 I cover my notes on this area.  At a glance, you might also need to comment out the wpa-conf in /etc/network/interfaces in addition to setting up the dhcpcd.conf data.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5538

Comment: has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this at home? Maybe a better route might be to set up a static IP on your router instead. Most routers allow you to give a static IP.

Comment: will try that. it's a zyxel

Comment: You should most definitely be able to set the IP on it. You may have to look at the list of connected devices and then make a reserved or static IP. You may have to get the MAC Address of the Pi. If you don't know how, you can use the ifconfig command.